# HTML button to direct to PayPal Gving Fund not working

Tags: html, paypal

Can someone tell me why this codes will not link to the page?

```
<form><input class=”MyButton” type=”button” value=”PayPal Giving Fund”   onclick=”window.location.href=’paypal.com/us/fundraiser/charity/1521457//button- links.php'” /></form>
```

I have also tried

```
<form><input class="MyButton" type="button" value="PayPal Giving Fund" onclick="window.location.href='htpps://www.paypal.com/us/fundraiser/charity/1521457/button-links.php'" /></form>
```

Neither work.  Says page cannot be found.

Comment: "why this codes will not link to the page?" **What code?**

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO :) Please edit your question with the actual code you want us to look at.

Comment: <form><input class="MyButton" type="button" value="PayPal Giving Fund" onclick="window.location.href='htpps://www.paypal.com/us/fundraiser/charity/1521457/button-links.php'" /></form>

Comment: It's `https://`, not `htpps://`. And make sure link points to where it should. First code sample must use proper quotes and link must start with `{protocol}://` in order to redirect to another domain

Comment: I corrected the error and tired the code below. I still get an error.  It gives me this page.  https://www.paypal.com/us/fundraiser/110230052184687338/charity/1521457/button-links.php

Answer (score 1):

try this
you had a typo in 'htpps' also use the action param of the form instead of a onclick, it's mean to do that

```
<form action='https://www.paypal.com/us/fundraiser/charity/1521457/button-links.php'>
    <input class="MyButton" type="submit" value="PayPal Giving Fund">
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe try explaining why `try this`?

Comment: https://www.paypal.com/us/fundraiser/charity/1521457/button-links.php  This is where the code takes me.

Comment: @RVS811 Yes, that is the link you provided in the example